# Sum a range of cells in a column that can be used in other columns to sum the same range in only that column

Tags: google-sheets

So basically, I want =SUM(F2:F5) except I want F to be a variable that only references the current column the formula is in. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(5, COLUMN())))
```